# How i convert integer value into string value in java

Tags: java, sql

```
String doc = String.valueOf(po.get_Value("DocumentNo"));
```

I used above code but still it's taking the integer value in the query.
Below I mentioned the query where I want the `String` value.

```
String sql = "update C_partial SET IsExported = 'Y' where documentno ="+doc;
```

Comment: ehm ... what exactly do you mean? no matter what type doc is at that point (it is a String, btw), through the concatenation, it would become part of a String. So what do you get as result that is not correct?

Comment: What do you mean with `Integer` value and `String` value? do you actually want the query to just end with `"...documentno = ' +doc + "'";`?

Comment: Please see JDBC PreparedStatement with particular reference to parameter placeholders, and also see SQL Injection.

Comment: the data type of document no column is integer, same i executed  in sql developer then i have put document no in '  '(Single quote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap with apostrophe characters

```
String sql = "update C_partial SET IsExported = 'Y' where documentno = '"+doc+"'";
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

```
String sql = "update C_partial SET IsExported = 'Y' where documentno =?";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, doc);
```

It is just [safer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java) and cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String.valueof();
```

like this and add ' to your query

```
String sql = "update C_partial SET IsExported = 'Y' where documentno = '"+String.valueOf(doc) +"'";
```

Comment: wouldn't change anything. doc already is a String, he already applied String.valueOf(...), and even if not, the concatenation itself would render it as a part of the String